# Why does React Native app crash when clicking on debug in Android emulator?

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, facebook

React Native app shows error when clicked on debug in Android emulator

Attempt to invoke interface method java.lang.String com.facebook.react.bridge.Cat alystInstance.getSourceURL('on a null object reference

below are error screenshots

Emulator screenshot:
[image: 1]

Debugger screenshot:
[image: 2]

When clicked on reload app crashes and lost connection to debugger.

Tried uninstalling and reinstalling apk in emulator and cd android ./gradlew clean.

Still same error.

Comment: If you don't turn on the debugger, there will be an error, right?

Comment: Did you installed react-native-reanimated?

Comment: yes -     "react-native-reanimated": "^2.2.0",
@thanhal

Comment: Then see my answer below

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have faced same issue and it was due to the **'react-native-reanimated'** package (It's mentioned in their documentation that remote debugging is no longer possible for react-native-reanimated : [React Native Reanimated Known problems and limitations](https://docs.swmansion.com/react-native-reanimated/docs/#known-problems-and-limitations)) and the solution is to use flipper to debug : [Debugging React Native apps with Flipper](https://blog.logrocket.com/debugging-react-native-apps-flipper/)

Comment: Hey, reanimated team member here. Remote debugging should be working now! We are also working on enabling the use of Flipper to debug worklets in this PR https://github.com/software-mansion/react-native-reanimated/pull/3526 !

Comment: @KarolWasowski I'm trying to use debugger (no flipper) and my debugger is still crashing on every refresh. Is there any trick to making these reanimated fixes work?

Comment: Hey @MoteZart, if you're talking about the changes made in the PR I linked, then it is a known bug I am working on right now. If you're using the normal Chrome Debugger (not Chrome DevTools) then everything should be working as in any other React Native app.