# app debbug crashing when run-android with no error on some phone such as samsung m205f

Tags: react-native, react-redux

app crashing in debug mode with no error in some phone like m205f and some phone are work good i use other react-native app and its ok
my package.json i try so many thing but nothing happens and still crashing on debbug mode
and apk is work fine without any crash or something unusual

"dependencies": {

```
"@craftzdog/pouchdb-core-react-native": "^7.0.0",
"@craftzdog/pouchdb-replication-react-native": "^7.0.0",
"@react-native-community/art": "^1.2.0",
"@react-native-community/async-storage": "^1.12.0",
"@react-native-community/blur": "^3.6.0",
"@react-native-community/masked-view": "^0.1.10",
"@react-native-community/netinfo": "^5.9.9",
"@react-native-community/push-notification-ios": "^1.5.0",
"@react-native-community/voice": "^1.1.9",
"@react-native-firebase/analytics": "^10.6.4",
"@react-native-firebase/app": "^10.8.1",
"@react-native-firebase/messaging": "^10.8.1",
"@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^5.9.2",
"@react-navigation/material-top-tabs": "^5.2.19",
"@react-navigation/native": "^5.7.5",
"@react-navigation/stack": "^5.9.2",
"axios": "^0.24.0",
"events": "^3.2.0",
"jalali-moment": "^3.3.10",
"lottie-react-native": "^3.5.0",
"moment": "^2.29.1",
"moment-jalaali": "^0.9.2",
"pouchdb-adapter-react-native-sqlite": "^2.0.0",
"pouchdb-find": "^7.2.2",
"react": "16.13.1",
"react-devtools": "^4.22.1",
"react-native": "^0.66.4",
"react-native-background-actions": "^2.6.5",
"react-native-barcode-mask": "^1.2.4",
"react-native-camera": "^3.44.3",
"react-native-chart-kit": "^6.6.1",
"react-native-circular-progress": "^1.3.6",
"react-native-device-info": "^7.3.1",
"react-native-exit-app": "^1.1.0",
"react-native-fast-image": "^8.3.4",
"react-native-fs": "^2.16.6",
"react-native-gesture-handler": "^1.10.3",
"react-native-image-crop-picker": "^0.35.2",
"react-native-image-picker": "^4.7.0",
"react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view": "^0.9.3",
"react-native-linear-gradient": "^2.5.6",
"react-native-modern-datepicker": "^1.0.0-beta.91",
"react-native-orientation-locker": "^1.4.0",
"react-native-paper": "^4.11.2",
"react-native-parsed-text": "^0.0.22",
"react-native-permissions": "^3.0.1",
"react-native-push-notification": "^8.1.1",
"react-native-qrcode-scanner": "^1.4.1",
"react-native-reanimated": "^1.13.3",
"react-native-restart": "^0.0.17",
"react-native-safe-area-context": "^3.1.8",
"react-native-screens": "^2.11.0",
"react-native-simple-gauge": "^0.3.0",
"react-native-size-matters": "^0.3.1",
"react-native-sound-player": "^0.10.5",
"react-native-splash-screen": "^3.2.0",
"react-native-sqlite": "^3.3.3",
"react-native-sqlite-2": "^3.1.1",
"react-native-star-rating": "^1.1.0",
"react-native-svg": "^12.1.0",
"react-native-tab-view": "^2.15.2",
"react-native-text-ticker": "^1.14.0",
"react-native-toast-message": "^2.1.1",
"react-native-vector-icons": "^7.1.0",
"react-native-video": "^5.1.0-alpha8",
"react-native-walk-counter": "^1.0.6",
"react-native-webview": "^11.0.2",
"react-native-wheel-pick": "^1.1.0",
"react-native-wheel-picker-android": "^2.0.6",
"react-redux": "^7.2.1",
"redux": "^4.0.5",
"redux-thunk": "^2.3.0",
"shamsi-date-converter": "^1.0.5",
"victory-native": "^36.2.0"
```

},

```
"devDependencies": {
"@babel/core": "^7.11.6",
"@babel/runtime": "^7.11.2",
"@react-native-community/eslint-config": "^2.0.0",
"babel-jest": "^26.3.0",
"babel-plugin-transform-remove-console": "^6.9.4",
"eslint": "^7.10.0",
"jest": "^26.4.2",
"jetifier": "^1.6.6",
"metro-react-native-babel-preset": "^0.63.0",
"react-native-bundle-visualizer": "^2.2.1",
"react-native-svg-transformer": "^0.14.3",
"react-test-renderer": "16.13.1"
```

},

does any library or dependency make this crash

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does React Native app crash when clicking on debug in Android emulator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70692613/why-does-react-native-app-crash-when-clicking-on-debug-in-android-emulator)

Answer (score 0):

First make sure to delete the node modules and re-install it then try this command

```
react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file index.js --bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle --assets-dest android/app/src/main/res/
```

Comment: what does this command do?

Answer (score 0):

I think it is due to `react-native-reanimated` package.
It is mentioned in their documentation that remote debugging is no longer possible for react-native-reanimated.

*As the library uses JSI for synchronous native methods access, remote debugging is no longer possible. You can use Flipper for debugging your JS code, however connecting debugger to JS context which runs on the UI thread is not currently supported.*

ref : [React Native Reanimated Known problems and limitations](https://docs.swmansion.com/react-native-reanimated/docs/#known-problems-and-limitations)

To use Flipper, refer this doc : [Debugging React Native apps with Flipper](https://blog.logrocket.com/debugging-react-native-apps-flipper/)

Comment: i change react native version to 64.2 and this problem fixed but the new issue is debbuger is soo slow when i press on something it take several minust to response

Comment: Check if the time is same in both device and system. Time difference in seconds can cause this issue.

Comment: i do this and nothing happend and the main problem is orientation locker this made app really slow